# LightOutMode(fullscreenactivity) of viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Can i implemt fullscreenactivity type thing using fragment?I just want to show some contents of my fragment on clicking the screen,and similarly hiding on clicking if already being displayed.I want to show lightoutmode(fullscreenactivity) in my viewpager.I don't understand how to implement.I want to handle this from my Fragment of viewpager but getwindowsfeature() and SystemeUiHider is implemented for Activity by default and i can't do it simply from fragment as it is static class in my case.Any help me out please.